# database wont update after clicking submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

After connecting to the database, here is the simplest code that should update my database after clicking the submit button :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET download='Yes' WHERE id=15 ";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form  method="post" >  

  <input type="submit" value="Update " name="update">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You never make any sort of connection between PHP and your database, and you also never actually **use** your `$sql` variable after assigning to it. I'd recommend having a look at W3Schools for the [*basic MySQLi / PDO update structure*](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to connect to a database.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Check connection if successful

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
}
```

If successful execute your query now.

```
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET download='Yes' WHERE id=15 ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Check if query succeeded.

```
   if( $result ) {
       echo "Update successful!";
   }
   else {
     echo "Updated Failed!";
   }
```

Comment: I made a connection just didnt write it up. Problem was that i didnt execute it, your review pointed that out to me. Thanx a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use error and exception handling codes, it will be helpful to fix the errors